# flatMap() in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

If i make a `Single` invocation using `Retrofit` as example in Kotlin, i want to check the resulted answer and keep going with a `Single` or an error. As example

```
model.doRequest()
     .flatMap { t: Response ->
          if(!h.hasError) {
              return@flatMap model.doAnotherRequest()
          } else {
              return@flatmap Single.error<Throwable>(Throwable("error))
          }
      }
```

If i make another `flatMap()`, `subscribe()` or any other things, RxJava won't know that I want to continue with response given by the `doAnowhtRequest()`, instead will return `Any!`. How i can get data given by second request?

In Java, `Single.error` isn't interpreted so RxJava will continue to give me the response in next invocations.

Comment: instead of `return` just `throw` the throwable and there's no need for a `return` statement then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to return the same thing as `doAnotherRequest()` the problem is with `Single.error<Throwable>(Throwable("error))`. You're hitting the compiler that you're returning a `Single<Throwable>`, but you want to return a `Single<whatever doAnotherRequest returns>`.

Say your `doAnotherRequest` returns `Single<Foo>`, then you'd want to return `Single.error<Foo>(Throwable("error))`, which will return a single that will emit an error with the given exception.

Kotlin tries to infer the type you want to return, but because you're returning 2 types that the "most common" type is `Any`, kotlin can only infer it's that you want to return.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!